# Navigation.navigate: was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using navigation for the first time, I'm creating a form to signup an user.

Now after the user makes the signup I would to redirect with the Home page using the user data.

I have made in this way:

**Registration.js**

```
const onRegisterPress = () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword){
        alert('Error passwords')
        return
    }
    firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((response) => {
        const uid = response.user.uid
        const data = {
            id: uid, email, fullName
        };
        const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
        usersRef
        .doc(uid)
        .set(data)
        //There:
        .then(() => {
            navigation.navigate("Home",{user: data})
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error)
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        alert(error)
    })
}
```

**App.js**

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
   <Stack.Navigator>
        { user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

After the signup (that works), I Receive the error message:

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home","params":
> {"user":{"id":"myid","email":"myemail","fullName":"myfullname"}}}} was
> not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

How can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

I have a feeling this is because you have two different navigators. React is probably looking for the `Home` screen inside the Auth navigator, and not finding it.

When you do

```
navigation.navigate("Home",{user: data})
```

It is from inside .createUserWithEmailAndPassword so the navigation object refers to the auth navigator.

What you can do instead of a direct "navigation.navigate" is at the root of you code, have a `if else`.

If logged-in return Navigator-with-home, else return Auth Navigator.

Have a loggedin setState that is controlled by `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`. Everytime the user is logged out, setState to false, everytime logged in, setState to true. Now, you are dynamically switching navigators. React won't get confused.

Example snippet:

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({loggedIn: true});
      } else {
        this.setState({loggedIn: false});
      }
    });
```

**Previous answer:**

Why didn't you put a `component` prop on the Home screen like you did for the others? That's how react finds which screen to serve, not by the name "Home", but by the `component` Home.

You should have:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component = {HomeScreen}>
```

If you want params, you can do:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component = {HomeScreen} initialParams={{extraData: user}}>
```

(I'm not sure if you need brackets around {user}. Try with and without.)
You can access `extraData` with `route.params.extraData`. Route is passed automatically along with navigation as a prop whenever you navigate to a screen.

So for class-based components, you can access it with `this.props.route.params.extraData`, and for functional-based, you can do `props.route.params.extraData` or access it directly `route.params.extraData` if you destructured it.

Comment: I have tried to use what you suggest to me, but I receive the same error

Comment: So you said that I shoul insert before the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` your snippet?  and in the `then(() => { })` ?

Comment: Put the snippet in your App.js. Then replace `{user? (...):(...)}` with `{loggedIn? (...):(...)}`

Comment: Ok I have add these in my code. Now after the signup if I go back I am redirect to the Home

Comment: you can add a prop to react navigator that prevents going back `gestureEnabled: false`

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to navigate manually.
Assuming `user` in App.js gets updated when the user logs in, the authentication stack will be unmounted, and the Home stack will appear instead.

More info here if needed: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't import the `navigation` prop from react-navigation.

```
import {useNavigation} from 'react-navigation'
```

Then in component:

```
const registration = () => {
   const navigation = useNavigation();

  const onRegisterPress = () => {
    // handle your Auth here
    navigation.navigate('home');

  }


  return(...whateveryourJsxIs)
}
```

This is assuming you're using a functional component.

Comment: I have imported this :)